# Cannot compile android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I downloaded a project and trying to build it but it's giving me so many errors.

FAILURE: Build completed with 6 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6).
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
> Could not resolve :volley-plus-release.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.ycuwq.widgets:datepicker:1.3.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.3.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. The issue was that I was using giphy and facebook sdk but now facebook is providing support for giphy so you don't need to add giphy sdk with facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the Manifest and the build.gradle with the dependencies used in this project? It seems that you did not import the dependencies, in your build.gradle see if they are there;

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.your_dep_here:1.0.19'
}
```

Comment: Yes. All dependencies are already there.

Comment: Have you added the build.gradle from the downloaded project?
There are dependencies that you might have to add google() or maven() in your repositories tag

Answer (score 0):

**Why its happening** :  JFrog has announced that they are shutting down the Bintray hosting service, which includes the popular JCenter hosting service for Java artifacts, as well as GoCenter (which hosted Go packages) and ChartCenter (which hosted Helm charts)
[image]

**Solution;**  Delete ***Jcenter()*** declaration from your main build.gradle file in your project root and use **google() mavenCentral() and
gradlePluginPortal()** instead.. Re-sync and Rebuild..

[image]